# How to enter in web interface ispconfig?

Tags: apache, ispconfig

Tell me please. There are vps on which are installed ubuntu 14.04 apache, php, mysql and ispkonfig. But I do not know how to get into the panel ispkonfig the web interface. What address should I dial in the browser? Or where you can see it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try your ip with port 8080

http://your-ip:8080

or you can view config file located in /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/lib/config.inc.php

Comment: Thank you. Works only through a secure protocol, https:// ip:8080
Since I did not install and configure, I did not think about it.